# Wordpress cannot find my database on phpmyadmin

Tags: wordpress, phpmyadmin, xampp

I'm currently in the process of installing Wordpress onto my Xampp in my Windows computer. After following this step-by-step installation guide: https://premium.wpmudev.org/blog/setting-up-xampp/?utm_expid=3606929-104.UORT_bNFTQmA2CgLFPRuGg.0&utm_referrer=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com%2F
I've made it to the Wordpress database information page. I've looked into my wp-config file for the information the page needs in order to find my database, and filled it out. But for some reason, Wordpress cannot find the database. I've checked that my username, password, and database host name was correct, and it was. What would cause Wordpress to reject my correct information?

Comment: It sounds like you're doing it backwards. Have you created a database in PMA and edited your wordpress config to match? If you're following that guide, your database host entry in your wp config should be 'localhost' and then you need to provide the user name, password and DB name you created in PMA

Comment: Where do I find that information in PMA?

Comment: It doesn't exist in phpmyadmin yet. You have to log into PMA and create a new database for your wordpress to use.

Comment: Oh. I've done that already. I'm in the process of trying to get Wordpress to find that database. so far no luck

Comment: are you following that tutorial directly? Is this all on a local computer you're using? if so, the wordpress config should use 'localhost' as the database host setting. The user/pass should be what you used to log into PMA, and the db name should be the same as the one your created in PMA.

Comment: please check your xammp control panel is their MySQL should be start

Comment: MySQL is on and running Raj Kumar Bhardwaj. I have followed the guide exactly user3689137.

Comment: Thank you user3689137 and Raj Bhardwaj for your help, but I just managed to solve my problem. Turns out that a password for my database didn't exist. all I needed to do was to simply leave the password text field blank.